# Make control for checkboxes by one button, using only HTML, CSS, SCSS and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I make some checkboxes and I have one button which should make all checkboxes default condition for all check boxes, like all turn on. I know better and easy way it's make by JavaScript, but I can use only HTML, CSS, SCSS and Bootstrap 4. If somebody make something before, please explain how to make like this. Default condition its "on"

```
        <div class="welcome-left-btn">
         <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked>
          <span class="slider round"></span>
         </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="welcome-left-btn">
         <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked>
          <span class="slider round"></span>
         </label>
        </div>

        <button id="defaultbtn" class="btn" type="submit">Defaultbtn</button>


        .switch {
         position: relative;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 40px;
         height: 23px;
         }
         .switch input {
         opacity: 0;
         width: 0;
         height: 0;
         }
         .slider {
         position: absolute;
         cursor: pointer;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         background-color: #ccc;
         -webkit-transition: .4s;
         transition: .4s;
         }

         .slider:before {
         position: absolute;
         content: "";
         height: 19px;
         width: 19px;
         left: 2px;
         bottom: 2px;
         background-color: white;
         -webkit-transition: .4s;
         transition: .4s;
         }

         input:checked + .slider {
         background-color: #3861fb;
         }

         input:focus + .slider {
         box-shadow: 0 0 1px #3861fb;
         }

         input:checked + .slider:before {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
         -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
         transform: translateX(17px);
         }
         .slider.round {
         border-radius: 25px;
         }

         .slider.round:before {
         border-radius: 50%;
         }
```

Comment: If you want a button to do something, you need to use javascript. It can be inline javascript, but it has to be javascript, nonetheless.

Comment: @Geshode, thank you for reply. Before I make by JS and its simple and work. But this is testing task for company and they say "I can use HTML, CSS and Bootstrap 4 only"

Comment: You should give us the task as described by the company. Like, does it have to be <button> or just a <a> styled as a button. Does it have to be the same checkbox, for just visually seem like the same checkboxes.. and so on. Your interpretation could be limiting the solutions.

Comment: @KevinKVarughese i make check box and button according the template, but its should have style like this, if you know how to make same functionality but with another tags its okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try playing around with :target selector, to at least mimick the behaviour you're looking for visually without using javascript.

Here's a hacky solution. Ideally you'd be using javascript anyway. You could avoid using the "button" tag inside the "a" tag and just set the class to "btn" if you're using bootstrap.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 23px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 19px;
  width: 19px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #3861fb;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #3861fb;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
  transform: translateX(17px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section,
section:target~section:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}

section:target,
section:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="visual_off">
  <div class="welcome-left-btn">
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
  </div>

  <div class="welcome-left-btn">
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
  </div>

  <a type="submit" href="#visual_on"><button>ON</button></a>
</section>
<section id="visual_on">
  <div class="welcome-left-btn">
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
  </div>

  <div class="welcome-left-btn">
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
  </div>

  <a type="submit" href="#visual_off"><button>OFF</button></a>
</section>
```